# Why the factors of a quadratic equation $ax^2 + bx + c$ are given as $(x - \alpha)(x - \beta)$ and not as $(x + \alpha) (x + \beta)$

Tags: roots, quadratics, quadratic-forms

When reading about the quadratic equations, I came to the relation between the roots of the $p(x)$ with $a, b, c$.

Standard form of quadratic equation is: $ax^2 + bx + c$. Now, this is written in my textbook:-

In general, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the zeroes of the quadratic polynomial $p(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, a \ne 0$, then you know that $x – \alpha$ and $x – \beta$ are the factors of $p(x)$.

But how can $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ be roots of $ax^2 + bx + c$ ?

$$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = x^2 - (\alpha + \beta)x + \alpha\beta [= ax^2 - bx +c ]
$$

and what is the problem in taking $(x + \alpha) (x + \beta)$ as roots. The only thing that changes is that zeroes  will be negative i.e. $ x = -\alpha$ and $x = -\beta$. These negative zeroes actually make sense, because for an equation where all the values are positive, some negative value for x will be essential to make the $p(x) = 0$. Also, I don't see that there are much change in relation of zeroes and coefficients of x.

$$ (x+\alpha)(x+\beta) = kx^2 + k(\alpha + \beta)x + k\alpha\beta \\
\text{comparing } (ax^2 + bx+c) \text{ with }( kx^2 + k(\alpha + \beta)x + k\alpha\beta)\\
a=k, b=k(\alpha + \beta), c = k\alpha\beta\\
\text{So, }\alpha +\beta = \frac ba\\
\alpha\beta = \frac ca
$$

Here the relations that
$$\alpha+\beta = \frac{-b}{a}\\
\alpha\beta = \frac ca
$$

are not much changed. There is a relation between the zeroes and the coefficients in either of the cases. Then why is it necessary to take roots as positive when it doesn't comply with the standard form of quadratic equation?

Comment: It is wrong to think that $\alpha$ is positive and $-\alpha$ is negative.

Comment: Questions should not be downvoted simply because they contain a mathematical error. It only signifies lack of clarity and shows that OP is confused about something.

Comment: It is shorter to write later $x=\alpha$ than $x=-\alpha$

Comment: Take care : $ax^2+bx+c=\color{red}{a}(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$: you are forgetting the $\color{red}{a}$...

Comment: @geetha290krm Why?, I mean that's what I'm supposed to think. And why to use negative factors for the sake of positive roots when we can have positive factors with positive relations and only negative roots

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Surely, but what about the relation $\alpha + \beta = \frac{-b}{a}$. I'd rather prefer a positive fraction than a negative one instead of a positive root at the place of a negative root.

Comment: Certainly it is easier to say $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots (zeros) rather than say $-\alpha$ and $-\beta$ are the roots (zeros). It is like answering the question "How to get to the post office?" by answering "go to 45 High Street" vs. answering "go to 44 High Street, then cross the road, it is exacly opposite". Note that this says nothing about whether $\alpha$ and $\beta$ themselves are positive or negative, it is just whether you get the answer straight away or in a roundabout way.

Comment: Is not the factors of the quadratic ($x-\alpha, x-\beta$) that are the roots. The values of x ($\alpha, \beta$ for which the factors equal zero) are the roots. The factors in this case are first degree polynomials that the quadratic can be divided by with no remainder.